# Submitting Form With jQuery and Altering DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a 401k calculator that will take in a handful of inputs (and assign a couple of others behind the scenes). I'm going to move toward some calculations and render a table of values in tabledata, but right now I'm just trying to change the value of tabledata div to "Testing" when a user submits. What am I doing wrong?

```js
jQuery(function () {
  $('#401k').submit(function () {
    var data = $("#401k :input").serializeArray();
    document.getElementById("tabledata").InnerHTML = "Testing";     
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="401k" action="#">
    <div class="row uniform">
      <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
        Percentage to Contribute:
        <input type="text" name="percent" id="percent" value="" placeholder="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
      <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
        Annual Salary Growth:
        <input type="text" name="salaryincrease" id="salaryincrease" value="" placeholder="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
      <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
        Current Age:
        <input type="text" name="currentage" id="currentage" value="" placeholder="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
      <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
        Retirement Age:
        <input type="text" name="retirementage" id="retirementage" value="" placeholder="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
      <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
        Current 401k Balance:
        <input type="text" name="currentbalance" id="currentbalance" value="" placeholder="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
      <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
        Expected Rate of Return:
        <input type="text" name="rateofreturn" id="rateofreturn" value="" placeholder="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="12u$">
      <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="special" /></li>
        <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </form>
  <div id="tabledata">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
```

Comment: Look into what is AJAX and how to make AJAX calls.

Comment: InnerHTML !== innerHTML

Comment: Please don't make us go to a 3rd party site just to see your code when you can just insert a code snippet right here in your question.

Comment: It's not clear what's not working.

Comment: Since this is a form for a calculator and not for submitting, you shouldn't be using a submit button in the first place. Just use a regular button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `innerHTML` property starts with a lowercase "i", so it should be written like that:

```
document.getElementById("tabledata").innerHTML = "Testing";
```

and if you don't want a page refresh, use `e.preventDefault()`, just like this:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#401k').submit(function (e) {
        var data = $("#401k :input").serializeArray();
        document.getElementById("tabledata").innerHTML = "Testing";
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, `$('#tabledata').html('Testing');`

Comment: I have incorporated these changes, trying both GelsonMR's method as well as isherwood's, and still nothing renders.

Comment: I assume it's not rendering because of the submit button, which makes the page refresh and also it reset all the changes, try using the `e.preventDefault()` to prevent that.